# Function Whose Tangent Always Normal to Another Function

Tags: derivatives, tangent-line

Please excuse me if my mathematical terminology isn't exactly precise or most eloquently worded - I'm an A Level student and this is my first question.

If we have a function, $f(x)$, can we define another function, $g(x)$, whose tangent at *any* value for $g(x)$ is normal to $f(x)$ within the same range for $x$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The tangent vector to $f(x)$ is $[1,\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x)]$, and to $g(x)$ it is $[1,\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x)]$. You want these vectors to be perpendicular
$$[1,\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x)]\cdot [1,\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x)]=0$$
so
$$1+\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x)\right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x)\right)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x)=\frac{-1}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x)}$$
which defines $g(x)$ up to a constant.